# switch from glOrtho to gluPerspective

Tags: c, opengl, glut, projection, orthographic

I have a car draw at (0,0) and some obstacles set up but right now my main concern is switching from glPerspective to glOrtho and vice-versa. All that i get when i switch from perspective to ortho is a black screen.

```
void myinit(){
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60,ww/wh,1,100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(-5,5,3,backcarx,topcarx,0,0,0,1);
}

void menu(int id){
    /*menu selects if you want to view it in ortho or perspective*/
    if(id == 1){
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glViewport(0,0,ww,wh);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-2,100,-2,100,-1,1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
    if(id == 2){
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(60,ww/wh,1,100);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        viewx = backcarx - 10;
        viewy = backcary - 10;
        gluLookAt(viewx,viewy,viewz,backcarx,topcarx,0,0,0,1);
    }
}
```

i've tried using the clear depth buffer and still doesnt work.

Comment: Little bit off topic but it seems you are using the fixed function pipeline. You should better switch to `Shaders` and `VertexBuffers` for better performance and better help ( I can't help you here because i'm not using the ffp anymore ).

Comment: Is the switching the problem, or that you can't see your scene properly using Ortho ? (If you init using Ortho instead of perspective, is the object visible ?)

Comment: yeah if i set it in ortho everything displays fine. its the switching thats the problem

Comment: changing from ortho to perspective is fine but the other way around i cant get it to work

Comment: Have you tried adding the gluLookAt statement in the GlOrtho branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mental roadblock lies here:

> ```
> void myinit(){
>     glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
>     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
>     glLoadIdentity();
>     gluPerspective(60,ww/wh,1,100);
>     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
>     glLoadIdentity();
>     gluLookAt(-5,5,3,backcarx,topcarx,0,0,0,1);
> }
> ```

OpenGL *is not initialized!* Yes, there are operations done only occasionally, like loading textures. But in general OpenGL is a state based drawing system. Which means, that you set all your drawing related stuff right before you use it. That code in the "myinit" function actually belongs into the display function. And once you have it there, it get's trivial to do the switching: Set a enumerating variable and setup the right projection at before drawing depending on the value of the variable.

As a general rule: OpenGL drawing operations – and setting transformation state belongs into that set of operations – belong into drawing code only. Hence your "menu" function makes no sense at all. It's an event handler. Event handlers deal with input, they don't generate output. In a event handler you change the value of variables and then you flag that output is to be performed.

---

#### Update due to comment:

```
typedef enum ProjectionType_t { Ortho, Perspective } ProjectionType;

ProjectionType projection;

void onMenu(int entry)
{
    swtich(entry) {
    case ...:
        projection = Ortho; break;
    case ...:
        projection = Perspective; break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(...);

    glViewport(...);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    switch(projection) {
    case Ortho:
        glOrtho(...); break;

    case Perspective:
        gluPerspective(...); break;
    }    

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    ...

}
```

Comment: this still doesnt help the change from perspective to ortho. i can change ortho to perspective fine but i can go back to ortho when in perspective

Comment: @Knitex: See my answer update for a coarse outline of how to do it.

Comment: this got the switching back to ortho working but for some reason now ortho to perspective doesnt work